# Python Tkinter help needed to create dropdowns and perform required operation

Tags: python, tkinter

I can create the below option menu but my question is when I select any value from dropdown it should display value stored in a variable 'a' for c[4] , value stored in a variable 'b' for C[5] and for all others it should show text "none available".

I have tried to cut short as far as possible.

```
        master = Tk()
    variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set("Summary")
w = OptionMenu(master, variable, c[0], c[1], c[3],c[4],c[5],c[6],c[7])
w.pack()
mainloop()
```

How should I print the output do I need to use

```
'def ok():print("value is", var.get())'
```

and then a button:

```
button = Button(master, text="OK", command=ok)
```

Comment: That function seems ok

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: yes I have tested it but it is not giving values for different conditions it gives one value for all the dropdowns whereas I want different values for different dropdowns. Could you suggest an amend

Comment: for example if we select c[0] from dropdown the above function will print "value is +the value from dropdown" whereas what I want is that when we select c[4] the value should be the value which is stored in a variable a which I have already defined , for C[5] it should be value stored in a variable b and for every other dropdown it should just print "none"

Comment: You need to use a lambda statement when you assign the function for the button, so that it reevaluates the value in the dropdown each time the button is pressed. If you don't want it to just print the drop down selection, you need to use the selection to find your data, I don't know how your data is set up so I can't help you with that

Comment: I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the Tkinter OptionMenu widget, and create a text variable to track the value of the selection. You can call .get() on the variable to find out what's selected.
ie.

```
s = tk.StringVar()
tk.OptionMenu(window, s, c[0], c[1]...  )

def function(x):
    # use x to find data
    ...

button = tk.Button(window, text='Button', command= lambda x=s.get() : function(x) )
```

You need a button aswell, so keep the one you've got and the command should use .get() to get the dropdown selection, then you can use that info to find your data.

The effbot docs are quite good for explaining how to use tkinter widgets.

Comment: do you want me to put above command in place of the button I created or in place of labels ?

Comment: Should be in place of the labels.

Comment: Thanks but I need a bit more amend. I have an access database file. in the above code line 'cur.execute("select name from businessdatabase")
'             I want to put each name in a dropdown list and when I click each name I get a particular data which I will add myself           but I need a syntax for this

Comment: for each dropdown which will be c[0],c[1].....c[7],  when I click on each of these the data displayed for c[3] should a and c[4] should be b and for every other I;e c[0],c[1],c[2],c[5],c[6],c[7] it should be a text saying 'none'. Please help with this

Comment: @strava  please help

Comment: @ scotty3785 please help

Comment: I've edited my answer, replace the labels with the drop down and keep the button

Comment: @ strava i have edited my code , now need help with priniting the output . please have a look at the edited post